# How to train parameters that are written in nested list in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I build a model AdaFDNN. Below is part of my definition of the model.

```
class AdaFDNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_covariate=5,
             num_hidden_layers = 4, # L-1
             total_num_layers = 5, # L
             neurons = [10, 10, 10, 10, 1],
             train_size = 128,
             grid=(0, 1), # grid is time idx
             dropout = 0.1, lambda1 = 0.0, lambda2 = 0.0, device = None):
    super().__init__()
    self.train_size = train_size
    self.num_covariate = num_covariate
    self.lambda1 = lambda1; self.lambda2 = lambda2; self.device = device
    self.num_hidden_layers = num_hidden_layers; self.total_num_layers = total_num_layers
    self.neurons = [*neurons, 1]; self.aug_neurons = [num_covariate, *neurons]
    # grid should include both end points
    self.grid_array = np.array(grid)
    # send the time grid tensor to device
    self.t = torch.tensor(self.grid_array).to(device).float()
    self.h = torch.tensor(self.grid_array[1:] - self.grid_array[:-1]).to(device).float()
    self.bias_para = [[nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), 1))) 
                                        for k in range(self.neurons[l])] for l in range(self.total_num_layers)]
    self.weight_para = [[[nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), len(self.t))))
                                           for j in range(self.aug_neurons[l])]
                                          for k in range(self.neurons[l])] for l in range(self.total_num_layers)]
```

I have to use self.bias_para and self.weight_para. Both of them are nested lists that should be updated. Thus I use nn.Parameter. However, it cannot run and I later figure out that I should add nn.ParameterList as well. However, I try both

```
    self.bias_para = nn.ParameterList([[nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), 1))) 
                                        for k in range(self.neurons[l])] for l in range(self.total_num_layers)])
    self.weight_para = nn.ParameterList([[[nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), len(self.t))))
                                           for j in range(self.aug_neurons[l])]
                                          for k in range(self.neurons[l])] for l in range(self.total_num_layers)])
```

and

```
    self.bias_para = nn.ParameterList([nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), 1))) 
                                        for k in range(self.neurons[l])]) for l in range(self.total_num_layers)])
    self.weight_para = nn.ParameterList([nn.ParameterList([nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), len(self.t))))
                                           for j in range(self.aug_neurons[l])])
                                          for k in range(self.neurons[l])]) for l in range(self.total_num_layers)])
```

and I obtain an error message 'TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.nn.modules.container.ParameterList' object to parameter '0' (torch.nn.Parameter or None required)'. What should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A `nn.ParameterList` is supposed to hold a single list of `nn.Parameter` and cannot contain other `nn.ParameterList`s. You can have a single comprehension instead of creating multiple levels.

The following code will register all those parameters on your `nn.Module` successfully:

```
self.bias_para = nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), 1)))
                                    for l in range(self.total_num_layers)
                                    for k in range(self.neurons[l]) ])

self.weight_para = nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(torch.randn((len(self.t), len(self.t))))
                                    for l in range(self.total_num_layers)
                                    for j in range(self.aug_neurons[l])
                                    for k in range(self.neurons[l]) ])
```